# Some Issues about Using BroadcastReceivers

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, activity-lifecycle, intentfilter

I want to use `BroadcastReceiver` in my application as `AsyncTask` result indicator in different `Activities` and therefore `AsyncTasks` too. I think my approach is little wrong or I missed something.

Here what I'm doing: Firstly, during `onCreate` I registered my receiver as a `BroadcastReceiver` using the `registerReceiver` method. My receiver looks like:

```
protected BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("some_msg");
        Log.i("Tutorial", msg_for_me);
    }
}
```

In my application, I've **A and B activities**. Each have different receivers which getting messages from different tasks. By the way, I must clarify that, A activity starting B activity.

I'm using receiver which in activity A, then activity A starting B using the `startActivity`. In activity B, I'm executing an `AsyncTask` and on `onPostExecute` I'm sending a broadcast with B activity's context. But somehow still A activity's receiver getting message. Both receivers have the same content but have different names.

So here are my issues:

- Should I `unregisterReceiver` when I started new activity on `onPause` method?
- Is `BroadcastReceiver` that how I'm using, only for one call? Should I register again and again whenever I send any message?
- I'm pretty sure I didn't define any receiver to `Manifest`. I suppose this is what I'm doing wrong. If this is well, how can I use IntentFilter while sending broadcast?

Please let me know if there is uncertain question. Any clues about BroadcastReceiver would be great and appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you should unregister broadcast receiver on activity pause. It
   is the potential leak.
2. No broadcast receivers are not for one call.
   They are called everytime the broadcast is done for the registered
   intents.
3. You can register the receiver for particular intent on
   OnResume like this,

mContext.registerReceiver(iReceiver, new android.content.IntentFilter("android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"));

Where iReceiver is ,

```
 iReceiver = new IntentReceiver();

private class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String LOG_TAG="IntentReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

    }
 }
```

and unregister the same on OnPause

```
mContext.unregisterReceiver(iReceiver);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still B activity's receiver not working well. Even if I send broadcast with using B activity's context, A activity's receiver getting message. Do you any suggestion? By the way, this is my main problem. I'll accept it as soon as someone solved this issue.

Comment: Can you edit your question with code from Activity A  and B? I can try to help more on that.

Comment: VendettaDroid, thank you again. I've found my wrong myself. No need to update anymore.